# Trouble with rescaling path

Tags: android, canvas, path, zooming, scale

I'm having some trouble trying to rescale a drawn Path. I managed to get the path to stay at the right position when zooming out, but I don't know how to scale it correctly.Additionally, twhen zooming out the app draws a line, connecting the first Point with the last Point of my Path and I have no Idea why.

Here are some images to explain what I mean:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3VCp.png) you can see how it looks like before I try to zoom.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwayA.png) you can see how it looks like after zooming.( I drew the red lines afterwards to show you how the path changes it's size. You can also see the straight Line, which was somehow added after zooming.)

Here is my onDraw Method:

```
    @Override
          protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
              super.onDraw(canvas);

              canvas.save();
              canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
              drawCoordinateSystem(canvas, mPosX, mPosY);

              if (drawMode == false) {
                  path.reset();
                  path.moveTo((lastTouchX/displayWidth) * (displayWidth/mScaleFactor) , (lastTouchY/displayHeight) * (displayHeight/mScaleFactor));


              for (int i = 0; i <= pathPointsX.size() - 1; i++) {
                  float mPointX = (pathPointsX.get(i)/displayWidth) * (displayWidth/mScaleFactor);
                  float mPointY = (pathPointsY.get(i)/displayHeight) * (displayHeight/mScaleFactor);


                  path.lineTo(mPointX, mPointY);

                  } 

              canvas.drawPath(path, paintL);
              } else {
              canvas.drawPath(path, paintL); }
              canvas.restore();


          }
```

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: both canvas and path can use matrix to transform itself

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by this? I think i managed to calculate the right matrix, following [this tutorial:](http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/)

But which commands do I use and where in my code du I use them? I tried:        
'path.transform(matrix);'
'canvas.setMatrix(matrix);'

But these doesnt seem to work.